# What is the best way to rename foreign key column?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new in Laravel , so i have a problem ,I have two tables villes(id,nom_ville,image) and quartiers(id,nom_quartier,id-ville)
i try to show a table of data which include and I found this problem

[this is my view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLNDu.png)

[Quartier Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1GyN.png)

[Ville Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PEIC.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHZ8H.png)

Comment: Please post code instead of images

Comment: Sorry I'm new on stackoverflow . . I don't know how to post a code

Comment: Refer to [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Read this to create better questions, it could help to have better and fast answers. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51144/how-do-i-post-code-in-stackoverflow?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Turns out your image links show the same class twice (pls paste code in future), but the answer below should still work...

--

Firstly you have the wrong types of relationship set up. This looks like a one to many where 1 ville `hasMany` quartiers. 1 quartier therefore `belongsTo` a ville.

Secondly as you say you have a non-standard key name, so you need to define it:

```
public function ville()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Ville', 'id-ville');
}
```